# Switch iPhone 4S's provider

Tags: iphone

I have a iPhone 4S and I dropped it in water and can't talk on it now. So my buddy gave me his old iPhone 4S. But the catch is that he has a passed due balance with "Telus". And I need the phone to run on the "Bell" network. How do I do that? I've heard it's possible. I've already jailbroke it.

How can I switch providers?

Answer (score 1):

Just exchange the sim card with a "Bell network" sim card,

or go to settings->carrier->automatic->off->and select Bell